# Include es6 class from external file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a file `class.js`:

```
class myClass {
   constructor(arg){
      console.log(arg);
   }
}
```

And I wanted to use the `myClass` class in another file. How would I go about this?
I've tried:
`var myClass = require('./class.js');`
But it didn't work.
I've looked at `module.exports` but haven't found an example that works for es6 classes.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Either do

```
module.exports = class MyClass {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }
};
```

and import with

```
var a = require("./class.js");
new a("fooBar");
```

---

or use the newish syntax (may require you to babelify your code first)

```
export class MyClass {
    constructor(arg){
        console.log(arg);
    }
};
```

and import with

```
import {myClass} from "./class.js";
```

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Answer (score 3):

```
export default class myClass {
   constructor(arg){
      console.log(arg);
   }
}
```

Other file:

```
import myClass from './myFile';
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I suspect I have an outdated version of node.

Comment: @BaldBantha this is because this is new ES6 syntax, you're going to need to use babel to transpile your ES6 to ES5 so node can run it. Node doesn't support `import`/`export` and never will (at least in the near future)

Answer (score 1):

```
export class MyClass
{
   constructor(arg){
    this.arg = arg;
}
}

import {MyClass} From'./MyClass.js'

class OtherClass{
 arg_two;

}

import {OtherClass} From'./OtherClass.js'

class1 = new OtherClass();
class1.arg_two.arg = 'class';

console.log(class1.arg_two.arg);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes