# Protractor - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, automated-tests

I wrote some tests in Protractor, but sadly I have little problem with import/export files.

**HomePage.js**

```
export default class HomePage {
  constructor() {
    this.path = 'http://automationpractice.com/index.php';
    this.searchQuery = element(by.css('.search_query'));
    this.searchButton = element(by.name('submit_search'));
    this.signInButtonHeader = element(by.css('.header_user_info'));
    this.emailInput = element(by.id('email'));
    this.passwordInput = element(by.id('passwd'));
    this.logInButton = element(by.id('SubmitLogin'));
  }
}
```

**homepage-spec.js**

```
import HomePage from '../page_objects/HomePage';
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
const homePage = new HomePage();
beforeEach(async () => {
  browser.get(homePage.path);
});
describe('Homepage', () => {
  it('should have a title', () => {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My Store');
  });
  it('Log into your account', () => {
    homePage.signInButtonHeader.click();
    homePage.emailInput.sendKeys('testprotractor@gmail.com');
    homePage.passwordInput.sendKeys('xxxx');
    homePage.logInButton.click();
  });
  it('Check categories', () => {
    element(by.linkText('Women')).click();
  });
});`
```

**conf.js**

```
const SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
require('@babel/register');

exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
 capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
 },
 suites: {
    homePage: 'specs/homepage-spec.js',
    searchResults: 'specs/search-results-spec.js',
  },
  onPrepare: () => {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true,
      },
    }));
  },
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "protractorautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is my test",
  "main": "conf.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^13.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Protractor"
  ],
  "author": "Xxxx",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Whenever I run tests, receive this error:

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import
>   HomePage from '../page_objects/HomePage';    ^^^^^^^^
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
> at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
> at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
> at Module._compile   (C:\Users\X\Documents\protractorAutomation\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24)
> at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
> at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\Users\Mati\Documents\protractorAutomation\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3) [16:53:29] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
> ```

Anyone can help me fix this problem?

Comment: Is that correct that you are trying to import the homepage PO from within homepage.js itself?

Comment: @DublinDev Sorry I mistakely pasted same code for HomePage.js, homepage-spec.js in first post. I just corrected first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the es6 style of imports you are attempting to use are not supported natively in NodeJS.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005332/include-es6-class-from-external-file-in-node-js) you have two options. I have created an example of the first for you to try.

```
module.exports = class HomePage {
  constructor() {
    this.path = 'http://automationpractice.com/index.php';
    this.searchQuery = element(by.css('.search_query'));
    this.searchButton = element(by.name('submit_search'));
    this.signInButtonHeader = element(by.css('.header_user_info'));
    this.emailInput = element(by.id('email'));
    this.passwordInput = element(by.id('passwd'));
    this.logInButton = element(by.id('SubmitLogin'));
  }
}
```

Change Import to require

```
//Change import statement to standard require
let HomePage = require('../page_objects/HomePage');
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
const homePage = new HomePage();
beforeEach(async () => {
  browser.get(homePage.path);
});
describe('Homepage', () => {
  it('should have a title', () => {
    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('My Store');
  });
  it('Log into your account', () => {
    homePage.signInButtonHeader.click();
    homePage.emailInput.sendKeys('testprotractor@gmail.com');
    homePage.passwordInput.sendKeys('xxxx');
    homePage.logInButton.click();
  });
  it('Check categories', () => {
    element(by.linkText('Women')).click();
  });
});
```