# Node.js use imports without module name

Tags: javascript, node.js, import

utilities/calculator.js

```
export default class Calculator {
    // class functions here
}
```

utilities/converter.js

```
export default class Converter {
    // class functions here
}
```

utilities/index.js

```
import Calculator from './calculator';
import Converter from './converter';

export {
      Calculator: Calculator.default,
      Converter: Converter.default
};
```

app.js

```
import Utilities from './utilities';

const calculator = new Utilities.Calculator(); // I want to call it like new Calculator();
const converter = new Utilities.Converter(); // I want to call it like new Converter();
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Nodejs uses CommonJS module system and you've written ES Modules. Please explain a bit more. Where are you expecting to run the code? Browser with some module bundler? Or directly in Nodejs? Also notice when you do `import someModule from './someModule'`, you are importing the `default` only. Also `export { Calculator: Calculator.default }` is a syntax error. You will find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795819/when-should-i-use-curly-braces-for-es6-import

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include es6 class from external file in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005332/include-es6-class-from-external-file-in-node-js)

Comment: `import {Calculator, Converter} from './utilities';`

Comment: Done thanks Scott and Swashata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.js, you can use `import { Calculator, Converter } from './utilities';` and your code should be like

```
import { Calculator, Converter } from './utilities';

const calculator = new Calculator();
const converter = new Converter();
```

Comment: is it possible to import all from that file at once and still be able to do it like this?